# Can the basis of a vector space span one another?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider a set of vectors $$S = \left\{ \mathbf{u}_1, \mathbf{u}_2, \cdots , \mathbf{u}_n \right\}$$ and a field of scalars $F$. Now propose a (proper) subset $A\subset S$.

If $$\operatorname{span}A=\operatorname{span}S$$ can $S$ still form the basis of a vector space over $F$? In other words, must the basis of a vector space be as succinct as possible?

My research suggests not, but that does not satisfy my curiosity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A=S$, yes. If $A\varsubsetneq S$, no. In fact, if $v\in S\setminus A$, then, since$$v\in \operatorname{span}S=\operatorname{span}A,$$$v$ can be expressed as a linear combination of elements of $A$. Since $A\subset S$, $S$ cannot be a basis: it is not linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

a basis is a set of exactly n independent vectors

you can have set of m>n vectors which span the space but it is not a basis because m-n vectors in the set are not linearly independent

Comment: I don't understand the downvote for this answer. OP asks when a spanning set is a basis. This answer tells clearly when it is not whcih is equivalent.

Comment: @P Vanchinathan Tanks, I was wondering the same :)

Answer (score 1):

Basis of a vector space, first of all, a subset of the vector space. It should span the space and be linearly independent.

So if a new set spans the vector space it will contain every basis *in its span*. But the spanning set should be pruned down to become linearly independent (remove excess baggage), then it will be a basis.